# How do I get my "Select a State" option to appear in my select menu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dropdown, html-select

I’m using Rails 4.2.7.  I have this code for displaying a select menu in my view

```
<%= addr.select :state_id, @states.collect {|s| [ s.name, s.id ]}, {selected: !@user.address.nil? && !@user.address.state.nil? ? @user.address.state.id : nil, prompt: 'Select State'}, class: "selectField selectMenu form-control"  %>
```

Problem is, when the code is rendered, the “Select a State” option is not present.  I included the “prompt:” as per the documentation so I’m not sure what else I should do to get the select option to appear.  What renders is

```
<select class="selectField selectMenu form-control select-hidden" name="user[address][state_id]" id="user_address_state_id"><option value="3526">Alabama</option>
<option value="3556">Alaska</option>
<option value="3547" selected="selected">Arizona</option>
<option value="3510">Arkansas</option>
…
<option value="3554">Wyoming</option></select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prompt will only display when there is currently no option selected. If you want to display the "Select State" option anyway, you can use `include_blank: 'Select State'` instead. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html